# Kendo UI Jquery vs Kendo UI Angular

Tags: jquery, angular, user-interface, kendo-ui

Require the comparison information about the KENDO UI JQUERY versus Kendo UI Angular? Currently using Kendo UI Jquery planning to migrate it on KENDO UI Angular.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `KENDO UI Angular` because it has almost all jQuery components and in Angular you can easily integrate them.

I have used them in Angular 4 project. Easy to integrate and easy to use with good performance.

More Info : https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/

Components : https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/

Comment: any difference information regarding keno ui jquery vs kendo ui angular

Comment: You can now use Kendo UI for Angular 5 as well, Its better to avoid use of jQuery in Angular. Kendo UI Angular doesn't need jquery.

Comment: Yes I agree bro, as need to show the differences to Client as already using licenses kendo UI jquery so they require justification for migration.

Comment: The Kendo UI Professional license (and all DevCraft licenses that include Kendo UI Professional) also include Kendo UI for Angular as well. Refer : http://telerik.com/forums/kendo-ui-for-angular-license-seperate

Comment: i presonally preffer jQuery version (at least for one or two years) because jQuery version is older and More mature than Angular version, as an example compare the feature of treeview jQuery version vs the treeview Angular version. also there number of components in jQuery version is more professional and has more version than Angular counterpart

Comment: Another thing to add up on this could be the translation to other frontend jQuery can be used on any frontend